# How to use Modernizr for input type=datetime?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, modernizr

I made a custom build for HTML input fields & attributes and included that on my page in the `<head>` but that's not working. What else do I need to do?

Comment: I answer both of these questions above.. but I'll repeat myself for you..

Comment: "What have I tried" I made a custom modernizr build and added it to my page. That is all. Period. Clear?

Comment: "What do I want to do" I want a polyfill or alternative for the html5 input type=datetime setup when it is not natively available. Clear?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the script they gave me `modernizr.custom.66777.js` and added it to the `head`. Why would it matter if I added it this way or by copying and pasting it into a script tag? (ie: why are you asking me this?)

Comment: It should not matter, I am just trying to figure out the problem of why it doest not work as you do not show any code. But if you added it this way it could be another problem then, either way i will just delete my comments...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what it is you are trying to accomplish, but the "Input Attributes" option adds tests for the following `<input>` attributes: `autocomplete`, `autofocus`, `list`, `placeholder`, `max`, `min`, `multiple`, `pattern`, `required`, and `step`. -- Not sure what this has to do with `<input type="datetime" ...>` elements?

The "Input Types" option does adds tests for the following `type`s of `<input>` elements: `search`, `tel`, `url`, `email`, **`datetime`**, **`date`**, **`month`**, **`week`**, **`time`**, **`datetime-local`**, `number`, `range`, and `color`.

However, from the documentation:

> These (input) types can enable native datepickers, colorpickers, URL
>   validation, and so on. If a browser doesn’t support a given type, it
>   will be rendered as a text field. Modernizr cannot detect that date
>   inputs create a datepicker, the color input create a colorpicker, and
>   so on—it will detect that the input values are sanitized based on the
>   spec.

In general, Modernizr doesn't "do" anything (besides the HTML5 shim), it just allows you to *detect for the existence of modern features* on the browser.

Comment: ah ok, it's a progressive enhancement tool, and I am looking for a graceful degradation tool. tyvm!

Comment: Indeed, that's a perfect way to describe it.  It allows you to do graceful degradation, but it doesn't "do it for you" so to speak.  Just gives you the tools necessary to do it yourself.