# Modernizr: Failing to execute datetime() on date input in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, modernizr

I'm using Modernizr and am having trouble getting a jquery UI datepicker to display in-place of the native html5 date input in FireFox.

**This fiddle shows what I mean - open it in FireFox**
When opening in Firefox I just get a text input
http://jsfiddle.net/Te2yL/

Code:

```
<head>
     //Include Modernizr - all items are included (full-fat version)
     <script src="assets/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
     <input 
         type="date" 
         id="start-date"  
         ng-model="someVariable" 
         format-date 
         class="form-control date" 
     />

     <script>

    Modernizr.load({
        test: Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
        nope: ['https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js',
        'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.22/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'
        ],
        complete: function () {
            $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });                 
        }
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

To confirm, when open in FireFox the Jquery-ui js & css are downloaded.

I'm still getting the text input show up in the browser - it's type is still 'date' on inspection of the DOM.

Am I missing something?

Many thanks

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197016/how-to-use-modernizr-for-input-type-datetime

Comment: I have checked out that question (and a lot of similar ones). I don't think it's a duplicate though because I am using the complete() function to then call jquery.datetime() i.e. i'm not just using modernizr and expecting it to be fixed? The fiddle also...

Comment: its a duplicate because the you using the complete function requires that the test be run successfully in the first place. It doesn't, so this won't work either.

Comment: The complete function does get hit though. Or is that not what you're insinuating?

Comment: In your fiddle, modernizr is not initialized: `TypeError: Modernizr.load is not a function`. Maybe there's a problem with it?

Comment: Did you open it in FireFox?

Comment: YES, I open it on Firefox v39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at the JavaScript of the [full, uncompressed version of Modernizr](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js) that you can include from cdnjs.com, there is this big comment at the top that says:

> ```
>  * Modernizr has an optional (not included) conditional resource loader
>  * called Modernizr.load(), based on Yepnope.js (yepnopejs.com).
>  * To get a build that includes Modernizr.load(), as well as choosing
>  * which tests to include, go to www.modernizr.com/download/
> ```

So, you will have to download a customized version from [the Modernizr website](http://modernizr.com/download) which includes `Modernizr.load`.

From the source code of a build of Modernizr with `Modernizr.load` included, I can see that the only code that glues Yepnope and Modernizr together is this line:

```
Modernizr.load=function(){yepnope.apply(window,[].slice.call(arguments,0));};
```

So, instead of hosting a customized Modernizr build at your own server, you can also include both Modernizr and Yepnope from cdnjs.com and then use this line of code to glue them together. Or you can just forget about `Modernizr.load` and use the `yepnope` function, for which `Modernizr.load` is just an alias.

Another problem is that you're using HTTP URLs for the scripts that `Modernizer.load` should fetch, which means they won't work when visiting JSFiddle over HTTPS. Consider [protocol-reliative](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) URLs or, better yet, always use HTTPS URLs.

↪ [See here for a fixed version of your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Te2yL/21/)

Comment: I have done this - The JS Fiddle was just easier to include than a code snippet - In my own code (which is the same as above (the modernizr call)) I include a Modernizr build which includes everything i.e. the full fat version

Comment: Have you opened the fiddle in firefox?

Comment: @Lee2808 The datepicker shows up when I open the [fixed Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Te2yL/21/) in Firefox, only the CSS isn't loaded because the full URL isn't used. If this doesn't solve your problem, it must be specific to the code you're using at your web site.

Answer (score 1):

I just pasted a simple modernizr custom build in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Te2yL/25/)* which seems to work for firefox.

However, I had to change the way you load jquery-ui css: simply replace that cdn with your desired theme:

```
    nope: [
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js',
      'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js', 
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css'],
    ....
```

user2428118 was right as `yenope` is not included in the standard dev build of `modernizr`, here the custom build:

[image]

*excuse the unloving paste as I did not want to host the custom build for that fiddle :)

*note*

I've posted the same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513023/uncaught-typeerror-with-modernizr-load/32223563#32223563) by accident, however it seems to be valid for that question as well..